# Change banner text color in wordpress or php/css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to php (and code in general) and have run into a problem..

I am using WordPress for my site, and I'm trying to change the color of the text within the [banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJMBr.jpg) at the top of the page . I can do this within WordPress, however whenever I do, it moves the text around on the main menu. Not sure why this is happening.

So I'm either looking for a way to fix this within WordPress, or what would probably be easier is to just change the font color within the .php page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit*

Not entirely sure what part of this question is off-topic, as it is entirely about one topic: How to change the colour of the text within a banner, within wordpress.. Whether that is through wordpress itself, or the back-end, I don't care. Whatever gets the job done.

Anyways, [here](http://www.ktsemm.com/training/) is a link to the site and the below is the style.css page.

Let me know if this isn't good enough, and the "main.min.css is needed

```css
@import 'layout/css/main.min.css';

#menu-item-27 span {color: #000;}

#contact-front{
 border: 0px !important;
 color: #fff !important;
     text-align: center !important;
}

#contact-contact{
 border: 0px !important;
 color: #000 !important;
     text-align: center !important;
}

#contact-us-page .section-content .wpcf7-form p .wpcf7-textarea {
 color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Don't have any one set title of Page with tag `<p>`,...

Comment: how the related code

Comment: Do you have a link to your page?

Comment: http://www.ktsemm.com/training/

Comment: `.header-navigation span {
    color: #000;
}` Add it to your style.css file in your themes.

Comment: Would that change it for all pages though? I have a few that need to stay white due to the image the text is placed on, while other pages such as the training page needs to be black in order to be visible.

Comment: If you want set only for Training. Try this `#menu-item-27 span {color: #000;}`

Comment: @jcottrell, can you please edit your quesiton correspondingly to avoid further tons of questions? Here are some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try add my comment to /wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css @jcottrell

Comment: @Farside Not sure what else I can do besides add a link to the page. That's the only question that has been asked....

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using p tag, which may have a padding/margin.

You can replace it with `<span style="color:black">Training</>`, but its not the best way to style an element.

Add the following css to your style.css

```
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a {
    padding-right: 0;
    position: static;
}
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li { padding-right: 16px }
#header .top-header .header-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children a:after { top: -2px; }
```

Comment: Got the same result. The training part of the menu was pushed down again

Comment: Did you remove the p tag from the title, because there is still a p tag with style attribute?

Comment: Ya, i replaced it with "<span style="color:black">Training</>" like you said. But it still looks the same

Comment: I have changed the my answer, please add the code above in your style.css